# C++ send any type of argument to a function

Tags: c++, function, types, arguments, void

Here it goes: I want to create a void function that will receive two well-known type of values and another one that could be anything. The code would be like this:

```
void change_settings(string element, short setting, ??? value) {
    switch (setting) {
        case ST_NAME:
            // Cast value to string or char* and change element.name
        break;
        case ST_AMOUNT:
            // Cast value to integer and change element.amount
        break;
        case ST_ENABLED:
            // Cast value to boolean and change element.enabled
        break;
    }
}
```

I tryied to make the value's type `const void*` but I get an error (`cast from ‘const void*’ to ‘short int’ loses precision`) because I just did this: `short name = (short)value`, which must be some crazy desperate trial, hoping to get lucky. Now, I don't know if there's a way of doing this, pass the pointer of whatever kind of variable then convert it to what it is (I know the type of variable to expect depending on each case.
How would I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you seem to know in advance all the potential types of `value`, and you want different behavior depending on the type, you can just write a series of function overloads:

```
void change_settings(const std::string& element, short setting, const std::string& value);

void change_settings(const std::string& element, short setting, int value);

void change_settings(const std::string& element, short setting, bool value);
```

This eliminates the need for a run-time switch.

Comment: That is true, but at that point why not create a different function for each setting and avoid the switch case.

Comment: Yeah - it makes the `setting` variable unnecessary.

Comment: Let's try this. Of course, I still can use switch and setting if I have different cases where I need an int value, for example

Comment: "ugly" b) option - make just one function with a `string` as parameter, and convert input in each call, `yourFunc( to_string(input) )` - simple example at http://ideone.com/qpo0UN

Answer (score 13):

You should use [templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

```
template <typename T>
void change_settings(string element, short setting, T value);
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! That would do it

Comment: The problem is that the cast in his run-time switch code won't compile when `T` is the wrong type.  I'd just write a series of function overloads

Comment: Indeed, that's what happens.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're talking about run-time switching (as opposed to compile-time, in which case templates are probably the answer):

You could consider a variant class (e.g. `boost::variant`), or perhaps use polymorphism (i.e. define an inheritance hierarchy, and virtual functions to implement the specific behaviours).

Comment: I suppose this is the professional way of doing this but I will keep it in mind for when I create some serious application. Thanks

Comment: you mean `boost::any` as the second option?>